# (JavaFX 8) button text on top of graphic

Tags: java, css, button, javafx-8

I use CSS to set an image to a button with this (example):

```
#button-id {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-graphic: url("/main/img/mybutton.png");
```

Now the image already contains the button text but I find that quite inelegant, since I'd have to create a new button graphic every time there is a new button with a different text. Setting the button's text via code (like `mybutton.setText("Text");`) only displays the text next to the button.

Using `-fx-background-image: url("myurl");` for the node displays the image weirdly tiled instead of the single image scaled to it's original size. Setting the size manually is quite uncomfy, too.

Also using panes between image and the button itself looks not very elegant to me. I really hope there's a better and simpler solution.

Any suggestions in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the tiling of the background image using the `-fx-background-repeat` and `-fx-background-size` properties:

```
#button-id {
    -fx-background-image: url("/main/img/mybutton.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-size: contain;
    ...
}
```

AFAIK there is no other way of stacking an image with the text other than using a `StackPane` that contains the image and the text as children as graphic, which cannot be done using CSS.

Comment: I completely missed those properties, big thanks to you!